# kaminari ActionView::Template::Error (arguments passed to url_for can't be handled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, actionview

I am suffering this error with kaminari, and after try a lot of different 'solutions' none of them works.
**kaminari is working in local environment.**
I read solutions in Stackoverflow and in others websites but not successfully.

The error in the staging/production:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation):
    11:     <%= first_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    12:     <%= prev_page_tag unless current_page.first? %>
    13:     <% each_page do |page| -%>
    14:       <% if page.left_outer? || page.right_outer? || page.inside_window? -%>
    15:         <%= page_tag page %>
    16:       <% elsif !page.was_truncated? -%>
    17:         <%= gap_tag %>
  app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb:14:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_kaminari__paginator_html_erb___1828213313480319639_70007980'
  app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_kaminari__paginator_html_erb___1828213313480319639_70007980'
  app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_kaminari__paginator_html_erb___1828213313480319639_70007980'
  app/views/orders/historical.html.erb:113:in `_app_views_orders_historical_html_erb__3179624665547326650_32720320'
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:102:in `historical'
```

Using:

- Rails 4.2.0
- ruby 2.2.2
- kaminari (0.16.3)
- kaminari-bootstrap (3.0.1)
- Try with default, bootstrap3 themes.

call to pagination:

```
<%= paginate @orders, :remote => true %>
```

Solutions I've tried:

- Change the eager_load to false.
- Use haml instead of erb
- Use remote => true when calling pagination.
- Delete rails UrlHelper from model class.
- delete views/kaminari

Anyone have any clue?
Thanks in advance.

regards

Comment: did you use serializer ?

Comment: can you try `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` into your order serializer ?

Comment: Thanks, I am not using serializer. I tried btw, adding the ActionView helpers in the assets config, but no luck

Comment: I have the same problem and none of the solutions described here works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this working using WillPaginate.
But I don't think is related with kaminari anyway.

Just changed to willpaginate and the configuration of eager-load in my environment to false, adn it works.
I guess I did not the change correctly the first time.

Anyway, I don't think this is a good solution. Eager-load should be a good thing in Production.
It might be some class loading something that eager-load doesn't like...
Hope it helps someone.